# Can you select multiple values from the same table row in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working in a SQL table where a string of information is stored in a single column/row for each high level object. This column stores information about what underlying objects they contain, each sub object denoted by a tag like [Report] Report1.... [Report] Report2... through out the text. There are a lot of underlying objects and tags and I need to be able to pull just the values after the [Report] tag.

Table structure

### |ObjectID|ObjectText|

|    1   | [Report]  report1 [date] 1 [Report]  report2 [date] 2 [Report]  report3 [date] 2| 
 
|    2   | [Report]  report5 [date] 1 [Report]  report8 [date] 2 [Report]  report3 [date] 2|

|    3   | [Report]  report1 [date] 1 [Report]  report2 [date] 2 [Report]  report2 [date] 2|

I am not sure how to do this and while I can use CharIndex() and substring() to receive the first [Report] tag and the value directly after it, I don't know how to get all the values from each row.

Select Substring(ObjectText,Charindex('[Report]', ObjectText) ,15) As Report
From ObjectTable

I have no control over how the data is stored in the table, I personally would not have stored such a long string of unrelated information in the same row.

Comment: Search for `split delimited column`  There are a number of functions available that will parse a string into multiple columns.  You might have to adjust them if they can't handle a delimiter like `[Report]`

Comment: This is a very bad data structure.  If you can, you should fix it to properly normalize it.  In the mean time, you can investigate the `split()` function to see if that will help (you can google it).

Answer (score 0):

Regarding splitting the data into arrays, hands down, one of the best sources of information on this for `SQL Server`:

http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql.html

An excellent read across the board.

Answer (score 0):

You may try doing it using following function:

```
create function ftStringsBetween
(
    @str varchar(1000),
    @tagStart varchar(50),
    @tagEnd varchar(50)
)
returns table as
return
    with [10](N) as (select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1
        union all select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1),
    [1000](N) as (select 1 from [10] a, [10] b, [10] c),
    v3(N) as (select top (isnull(datalength(@str), 0)) row_number() over (order by @@spid) from [1000]),
    v4(N) as (select N + datalength(@tagStart) from v3 where charindex(@tagStart, @str, N) = N),
    v5(N1, N2) as (select N, N2=isnull(nullif(charindex(@tagEnd, @str, N), 0), datalength(@str) + 1) from v4)
    select Value = substring(@str, N1, N2-N1)
    from v5
GO
```

You can apply it to your data as:

```
select o.ObjectID, rtrim(ltrim(fsb.Value)) Report
from Objects o
    outer apply ftStringsBetween(o.ObjectText, '[Report]', '[') fsb
```

And it will result to:

```
ObjectID    Report
----------- -----------
1           report1
1           report2
1           report3
2           report5
2           report8
2           report3
3           report1
3           report2
3           report2
```

[**SQLFiddle sample**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0a57f/2)